# CloudBees app deploy Platform error - {{invalid_local_plugin_dir,"/etc/genapp/plugi

Tags: cloudbees

I'm new to Cloudbees and having some difficulties getting my app deployed.
My app works in my local when using bees run. It also works when I placed it in another tomcat as Tomcat\webapps\ROOT.

In case it matters, I've added a lib:
C:\Java\cloudbees-sdk-1.3.1\biblenav\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar

My war file is 635 KB and I'm using the free account.

I've tried to deploy using bees deploy from C:\Java\cloudbees-sdk-1.3.1\biblenav\
and I've tried to deploy the war file from the bees root dir. Both times I get the error below. I've no idea what to do about it. Can anyone help? Thanks!

```
C:\Java\cloudbees-sdk-1.3.1>bees app:deploy -a angelwarrior/biblenav ./biblenav/webapp/biblenav.war
Deploying application angelwarrior/biblenav (environment: ): .\biblenav\webapp\biblenav.war
........................uploaded 25%
........................uploaded 50%
........................uploaded 75%
........................upload completed
deploying application to server(s)...
Apr 25, 2013 11:25:23 PM com.cloudbees.api.BeesClient applicationDeployArchive
SEVERE: Invalid application deployment response: angelwarrior/biblenav
com.cloudbees.api.BeesClientException: Server.InternalError - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform error - {{invalid_local_plugin_dir,"/etc/genapp/plugins.d/jar"},
[{genapp_plugin,validate_plugin_dir,1},
{genapp_plugin,new,1},
{genapp_deploy,resolve_plugin,2},
{genapp_deploy,apply_stages,2},
{genapp_deploy,handle_task,1},
{e2_task,dispatch_handle_task,1},
{e2_service,dispatch_info,2},
{gen_server,handle_msg,5}]}
at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClient.readResponse(BeesClient.java:1121)
at com.cloudbees.api.BeesClient.applicationDeployArchive(BeesClient.java:638)
at com.cloudbees.sdk.commands.app.ApplicationDeploy.execute(ApplicationDeploy.java:322)
at com.cloudbees.sdk.commands.Command.run(Command.java:167)
at com.cloudbees.sdk.commands.Command.run(Command.java:80)
at com.cloudbees.sdk.Bees.run(Bees.java:117)
at com.cloudbees.sdk.Bees.main(Bees.java:308)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.cloudbees.sdk.boot.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:35)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an unfortunately obfuscated error message, but based on on the details, it looks like you attempted to deploy the app at some point using a "-t jar" flag.  This sets your runtime stack to "jar", which isn't a known stack...which led to this downstream error.

You can see a list of valid stack names to use with that -t STACK flag in the CloudBees [ClickStack docs](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack).

In your case, it sounds like you'd like to run the deployed app package with Tomcat, so you probably want one of the following commands:

**For Tomcat 6:**

```
bees app:deploy -t tomcat -a APPID WAR_FILE
```

**For Tomcat 7:**

```
bees app:deploy -t tomcat7 -a APPID WAR_FILE
```

**For JBoss 7:**

```
bees app:deploy -t jboss -a APPID WAR_FILE
```

Note:  once you set the stack with -t, it is sticky, so you don't need to specify on subsequent deployments.

This was a confusing error for you to see, so we'll also look at cleaning up that error to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you! I tried the tomcat 6 version and it worked perfectly!I wouldn't be surprised if I'd tried the -t jar at some point